# XmStringGenerate() in XmMULTIBYTE_TEXT or XmWIDECHAR_TEXT mode

Tags: c, unicode, fonts, x11, motif

I'm trying to display some Unicode (Cyrillic, actually) using [`XmLabel`](http://www.vaxination.ca/motif/XmLabel_3X.html) and a server-side XLFD font (`-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1`). Whenever I use [`XmStringCreate()`](http://www.vaxination.ca/motif/XmStringCrA_3X.html) or [`XmStringCreateLtoR()`](http://www.vaxination.ca/motif/XmStringCrC_3X.html) as an `XmString` factory, the result meets my expectations.

When I try to use [`XmStringGenerate()`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/664558/numer/3/nazwa/XmStringGenerate) factory, however, passing in either `XmMULTIBYTE_TEXT` for a multi-byte Unicode string, or `XmWIDECHAR_TEXT` for a wide string, garbage is rendered onto the screen, regardless of the font used (I tried both `UTF-8` and single-byte Cyrillic server-side fonts).

The result can be seen below (the 1st 2 lines are ok, 2nd through 6th labels were created with `XmStringGenerate()` and are obviously **not** ok):

[image]

The complete code (requires Motif 2.1+ and a C99-compliant compiler) is [here](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/68bdf8420d6c7b7925f4).

Can anyone suggest a working `XmStringGenerate()` example suitable for displaying *Unicode* characters (not just `ISO-8859-1`)?

Comment: The ida prigram from fbida https://www.kraxel.org/releases/fbida/ uses XmStringGenerate and it works with UTF-8 text on my system. I'm not well versed in Motif so I can't tell you what exactly is different between it and your code.

Comment: @n.m.: Taken a look at `ida` source code. Basically, what I've found so far is `XmCHARSET_TEXT` can be used to display a multi-bute string in a locale-independent way: `XmStringGenerate(mbs, "UTF-8", XmCHARSET_TEXT, NULL)`. `ida`, on the other hand, uses `XmStringGenerate(mbs, NULL, XmMULTIBYTE_TEXT, NULL)`, but this works for Unicode locales only (setting `LANG` to `C` breaks the program unless it overrides the locale via `setlocale()` when started).

Comment: Yes, multibyte text is only UTF-8 if your locale is UTF-8. You know there are other locales, some with their own multibyte encodings different from UTF-8.

Comment: @n.m.: Thanks for the answer. Yes I'm aware of other multibyte encodings. I'll put my question differently then. Is it possible to use `XmMULTIBYTE_TEXT` and/or `XmWIDECHAR_TEXT` in a locale-independent way?

Comment: I'm almost sure that no it isn't possible with multibyte text. In practice widechar text is almost always UCS-4, so it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmMULTIBYTE_TEXT` is locale-dependent, as [n.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) suggested, and, aside from [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding#CJK_multibyte_encodings) (i. e. for Roman and Slavic languages), can only be used in `UTF-8` locales. Core X11 fonts can be specified as either **fonts** (`XmFONT_IS_FONT`):

```
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1
```

or **font sets** (`XmFONT_IS_FONTSET`):

```
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-*-*-*:
```

Speaking of `XmWIDECHAR_TEXT` mode, it seems impossible to specify a proper font with an explicit encoding, but setting a **font set** instead works perfectly for Motif 2.1 through 2.3.